# Sensenet Content Picker

Tags: sensenet

How can I initialize Content Picker for ReferenceGrid field control to display content from current workspace only?

```
<sn:ContextInfo runat="server" Selector="CurrentWorkspace" UsePortletContext="true" ID="myContext" />
<sn:ReferenceGrid ID="ReferenceGrid1" runat="server" FieldName="RelatedDocuments" 
TreeRoots='<%# myContext.Path %>'/>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's a property on the [Reference Field](http://wiki.sensenet.com/Reference_Field) called SelectionRoot. You can add it and change its value in the CTD xml of your ContentType

Comment: I want to set this dynamically in the content views, because there is no way to know the exact path value to set in the CTD xml.

myContext.Path returns correct value, I just have not been able to apply it to TreeRoots property of the ReferenceGrid.

Comment: Did you try the template parameters? http://wiki.sensenet.com/Content_Query_syntax#Template_parameters
Maybe it can be used also it in the CTD xml

Comment: Under ReferenceField (http://wiki.sensenet.com/ReferenceGrid_Field_Control):
**TreeRoots**: the allowed path roots in Content Picker's tree are by default defined in the Reference Field configuration (SelectionRoot element)
If I set in the following way:
 `<sn:ReferenceGrid ID="ReferenceGrid1" runat="server" FieldName="RelatedDocuments" 
TreeRoots='/Root/Sites/Default_Sites/workspaces2'/>`
it works fine.
If I set it as:
`<sn:ReferenceGrid ID="ReferenceGrid1" runat="server" FieldName="RelatedDocuments" 
TreeRoots='<%# myContext.Path %>'/>`
It does not work.